# cxf wsdl2java using gradle

Tags: gradle, cxf, wsdl2java, wsimport

I want to generate java classes from wsdl using gradle.
I have issues with wsimport so want to try using apache cxf.

I could only see cxf ant tasks wsdl2java.
Is there a sample example to do the same in gradle.

Note: I cannot use a random custom gradle plugins. I can use only approved plugins.

Comment: Does this help https://github.com/gmateo/apache-cxf-example/blob/master/build.gradle ?